# put method not working on RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView Django Rest Framework Angular

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, put, http-error, django-generic-views

I am attempting to make a put request in django rest framework. My view is inheriting from the RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView class.

I am using angular on the front end django rest on the back end.

Here is the error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)
ERROR 
detail:"Method "PUT" not allowed."
```

Here is the full implementation of the put request from angular side to django rest

```
editcity(index){
    this.oldcityname = this.cities[index].city;
     const payload = {
      citypk: this.cities[index].pk,
      cityname: this.editcityform.form.value.editcityinput
    };
     this.suitsettingsservice.editcity(payload, payload.citypk)
       .subscribe(
         (req: any)=>{
           this.cities[index].city = req.city;
           this.editcitysucess = true;
           // will have changed
           this.newcityname = this.cities[index].city;
         }
       );
  }
```

the service being called

```
editcity(body, pk){
    const url = suitsettingscity + '/' + pk;
    return this.http.put(url, body);
```

the url being mapped django side:

```
url(r'^city/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)',SearchCityDetail.as_view())
```

the view class

```
class SearchCityDetail(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = SearchCity.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SearchCitySerializer
```

the RetrieveUPdateDestoryAPIView documentation:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#updatemodelmixin

RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView
Used for read-write-delete endpoints to represent a single model instance.

Provides get, put, patch and delete method handlers.

Extends: GenericAPIView, RetrieveModelMixin, UpdateModelMixin, DestroyModelMixin

The RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView source code:

```
class RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                                   mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                                   mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                                   GenericAPIView):
    """
    Concrete view for retrieving, updating or deleting a model instance.
    """
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.partial_update(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Perhaps you have a clashing URL pattern, and the request isn't being handled by `SearchCityDetail`.

Comment: @Alasdair thats a good thought I'll look into it

Comment: @Alasdair so These two url patterns where in the opposite way they where now. I am getting a connection refused issue but I'll fix that and I think we might be good                                                        
  `url(r'city/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',SearchCityDetail.as_view()) # detele put get url
    url(r'city', SearchCityListCreate.as_view()), # create city list url`

Comment: @Alasdair I love you. It worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your URL pattern for the `SearchCityListCreate` was matching `/city/x/` so your request was being handled by the wrong view.

You fixed the problem by switching the order, but a better fix is to make sure your regexes have `^` and `$` to mark the beginning and end of the URL respectively.

```
url(r'^city$', SearchCityListCreate.as_view()),
url(r'^city/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$',SearchCityDetail.as_view()),
```

Comment: thanks @Alasdair I will make those changes right now

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it using rest_framework class view

```
class country_detail(APIView):
    def get_object(self,pk):
        try:
            return CountryModel.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except CountryModel.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404    

    def get(self,request,pk,format=None):
        country=self.get_object(pk)
        serializer=CountrySerializer(country)
        return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    def put(self,request,pk,format=None):
        country=self.get_object(pk)
        serializer=CountrySerializer(country,data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    def delete(self,request,pk,format=None):
        country=self.get_object(pk)
        country.delete()`
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to reverse the order of my city urls

the way it was, the city url with the pk was never taken.

Bad:

```
url(r'city', SearchCityListCreate.as_view()), # create city list url
url(r'city/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',SearchCityDetail.as_view()),
```

good:

```
 url(r'city/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',SearchCityDetail.as_view()), 
 url(r'city', SearchCityListCreate.as_view()), # create city list url
```